# How to find the very first conversation in chat with user?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-search

Hi is it possible to find very first conversation between me and another user?

How to search url for that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by between the two of you? How would the chat identify it? You don't even have chat privileges right now...?

Comment: @Tim the user has had the privilege on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we assume you @-replied to the user you had a conversation with you can use normal [search](//chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%40ShaniGoriwal&User=3557113&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) on chat (I took a conversation you had with a user named @ShaniGoriwal at that time as an example).

[image: search result screen shot]

Follow these steps to get to this result:

- Visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com/
- In the right top corner enter the user you had the conversation with in the search box and hit enter
- In the search result page enter your current username in the `when said by` box
- click `search again`
- Click `newest`
- navigate to the last page using the paging controls at the bottom (if there are more then 50 results)
- the last message on that page is your first interaction with that user

Notice that your previous username is recorded in the transcript.

Comment: I spend hours trying to find this. Good thing it is kept separate, which makes it easier to search and track. Thanks for the answer!